# Quick format of USB drive or external HDD

Tags: usb-drive, format

I remember that in order versions of Ubuntu, there was a GUI option for `Quick Format` of flash drive.

I am looking for a GUI app to format USB drive with one-click. A simple app to take care of partitioning, filesystem, etc rather than advanced ones such as `GParted`.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler option than Gparted is **Disks**

from terminal:

```
gnome-disks
```

or from GUI:

**System tools > Preferences > Disks**